# CXF RS: How do I tell the application to use my custom ExceptionMapper?

Tags: java, cxf, cxfrs

I found [this documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Exceptionhandling) that documents how to use an `ExceptionMapper`.  But it doesn't provide any information on how to tell the webapp that it should use it.  How do I configure that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your Spring configuration file like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="foo" address="/v2">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.MyExceptionMapper"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```